# AWS CloudFormation deploy overwrite "name" tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I like not specifying custom names for my resources (because of how CF won't rebuild them if changed)

But it would be nice if I could change the "name" tag at deploy time, for example:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file dev-cf.yaml --stack-name mystack --region us-east-1 --tags Name=myapp env=dev
```

Will this work or break anything? Does CF depend on the "name" tag of resources it creates?

Answer (score 0):

No, CF does not depend on Name tags, name tags are largely for your/sysadmins benefit. I haven't used many name tags (that's probably not a good thing) throughout a lot of stuff I've written and I've never had issues. The only thing that I can see being a possibility, is that CF does use some values/resource attrs/cf resource names to generate the CF specific names for things, so they may take your Name tags into consideration for generating those, but other than that, you'll be fine.